# Extracting kdb list values based on some condition

Tags: kdb

Say we have a kdb list

L1:(1 2 3 4 5)

Apply condition

L1 < 3

And how can I retrieve result in another list (1 2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [where](https://code.kx.com//v2/ref/where/) keyword for this:

```
q)l1 where l1<3
1 2
```

Applying `l1<3` will return a list of booleans `11000b`. Using where on this list will return the index of every 1b

```
q)where 11000b
0 1
```

Then indexing back into the original list will return the result in another list.